# OAuth2 Authentication Modes

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth

Recently in my ASP.NET Core application I was able to apply OAuth2 authentication with youtube documentation guidance:https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

... I would like to know if there is a way for my application to perform OAuth2 authentication without requiring a user authentication request. Being more accurate without the need to open an authentication screen for the user.

My idea is to automatically authenticate through the application with a google account already defined and work the API methods without the need for external authentication.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention . For the record, OAuth is concerned with Authorisation, not Authentication.

Comment: @pinoyyid , Thank you, it helped me a lot!